# WatchKit group: with image and label, image gets 2 of 4 corners rounded

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfaceimage, wkinterfacegroup

I'm trying to lay out a view in WatchKit with an image and a label side by side.

I create a Group with a Horizontal orientation, and add the Image with left justification and a label with right justification.

I actually get two different problems here:

(1) My image is square, but the edge of the image that is against the edge of the group gets rounded off.   So I have two rounded corners and two square corners, which looks bad.  I'd prefer to get 4 rounded corners -- but mainly I just need it to be consistent.

(2) My label text is long and needs to be wrapped.  In the Interface Builder I set lines to 2, and in IB it wraps properly.   But when I run it, the view in the simulator doesn't wrap, and instead is truncated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Post a link to the screenshot and someone will edit it in.

Comment: Screenshot:  http://i.imgur.com/KfcFflr.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a corner radius set on the containing group? If so it will clip the corners of the image.

Comment: Yes - the radius was set to 'default', by changing it to 'custom' and zero I was able to stop it from rounding the corners.

Comment: Rounded _is_ the default. Glad that part is figured out.

Comment: Also, seeing that the radius was an attribute of the group, I was able to round all 4 corners by creating a group containing just the image, then putting that group inside the group that puts the image and text together.  It seems that the label starting wrapping at that point as a side effect -- so getting exactly the look I want now.